# What is the proper way to insert in and join these tables?

Tags: c#, sql

I have three tables: Clients, Products and Orders

Clients:

```
ClientID - PK
ClientName
```

Products:

```
ProductID - PK
ProductName
ProductQuantity
ProductSize
Comments
```

Orders:

```
OrderID - PK
StartDate
FinishDate
Delivered
Billed
```

I have some different answers about my question, which is how to join these tables. Should i create a 4th table for the id's of the 3 tables or join clients and products in the orders table. Thing is that one client has one order of one or more products.
Please advise.

Code updated!

I have this code now which works only for client and products:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = GAMEWORK\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Tida; Integrated Security = True"))
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertClients", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
            using (var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("InsertProducts", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
            using (var cmd3 = new SqlCommand("InsertOrders", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
            {

                //-----------This works perfect
                if (TextBoxClientNou.Enabled)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeClient", TextBoxClientNou.Text);
                }

                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeClient", TextBoxClientNou.Text);
                }

                var IDClientParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDClient", SqlDbType.Int);
                IDClientParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var IDClient = (int)IDClientParameter.Value;
                con.Close();

                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Denumire", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Cantitate", SqlDbType.Int, 50);
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Dimensiuni", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Comentarii", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                var IDProductParameter = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@IDProdus", SqlDbType.Int);
                IDProductParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                con.Open();

                foreach (ListViewItem item in ListaProduse.Items)
                {
                    cmd2.Parameters["@Denumire"].Value = item.Text;
                    cmd2.Parameters["@Cantitate"].Value = item.SubItems[1].Text;
                    cmd2.Parameters["@Dimensiuni"].Value = item.SubItems[1].Text;
                    cmd2.Parameters["@Comentarii"].Value = item.SubItems[1].Text;
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }  //-----------------------Perfect


                //-------This does not work
                cmd3.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IDClient;
                cmd3.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd3.Parameters.Add("@DataInceput", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dateTimePicker1.Text;
                cmd3.Parameters.Add("@DataSfarsit", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dateTimePicker2.Text;
                cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Facturata", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = factstatus;
                cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Livrata", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = livstatus;

                cmd3.Parameters.Clear(); //---Only inserts the last product in the order table
                var IDProdus = (int)IDProductParameter.Value;
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientID", IDClient);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", IDProdus);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataInceput", dateTimePicker1.Text);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataSfarsit", dateTimePicker2.Text);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Facturata", factstatus);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Livrata", livstatus);
                cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //---------------------------
            }
```

And this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOrders]
    
    @ClientID int,
    @ProductID int,
    @DataInceput nvarchar(50),
    @DataSfarsit nvarchar(50),
    @Facturata nvarchar(50),
    @Livrata nvarchar(50)

AS
    
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Comenzi (ClientID, ProductID, DataInceput,DataSfarsit,Factstatus,Livstatus) VALUES (@ClientID, @ProductID, @DataInceput,@DataSfarsit,@Facturata,@Livrata);
    END
```

The problem is on the cmd3.parameters.Clear(). If i don't use it, i get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function InsertOrders has too many arguments specified.'
```

If i use it, only the last product in the form gets inserted in the orders table, no matter how many i add. Also, if i use cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery(); inside the foreach loop, it increments the order id and creates and order for each product in the list, which i don't want.

Comment: I think joining clients and products in the orders table is good idea, unless you need to retrieve these records more frequently. If you access the same records a lot of times, 4th table can be a good idea for sql performance.

Comment: For inspiration, look at [this simple model](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/customers_and_orders/index.htm) for students. It has a table between orders and products.

Comment: Is this about tables in a relational database or about classes in C#?

Comment: Consultant answer: it depends. It depends on your real scenario, but the point of view of the [enigmativity's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70222331/8093394) is the most commonly used in real world scenarios in my experience. That should be the accepted answer for your question.

Comment: This really sounds like you've totally changed what you're looking for in this question with your edit.

Comment: I didn't change anything, i just wrote the code for it (well...rewrote it a few dosen times to be honest), for which i encountered these errors. That is why i asked the question, because i don't know what is wrong, the tables architecture or the code.

Comment: @Chriss_1982 - It was "how do I join my tables" and it became "how do I fix these errors with my code". You should have asked a new question.

Comment: I finally managed to do it with a 4th table. Thank you very for everything :)

Answer (score 1):

If I assume correctly, that your existing tables look like this:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int Quantity;
    public decimal Size;
    public string Comments;
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id;
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime FinishDate;
    public DateTime Delivered;
    public DateTime Billed;
}
```

...then here are my initial suggestions:

Modify `Order` with a FK to `Client` so you know who placed the order.

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id;
    public int ClientId;
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime FinishDate;
    public DateTime Delivered;
    public DateTime Billed;
}
```

Then, because an order is an immutable record of a transaction, it ***should not link to `Product`***. So, create a new `OrderProduct` table, include an FK to Order and **copy all the fields** each time you create an order.

```
public class OrderProduct
{
    public int Id;
    public int OrderId;
    public string Name;
    public int Quantity;
    public decimal Size;
    public string Comments;
}
```

Now, if you have a product catalogue like this:

```
var products = new[]
{
    new Product()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Foo"
        Quantity = 500,
    }
};
```

...and you sell `1` "Foo" to "Fred" then the transactions might look like this:

```
var product =
    products
        .Where(p => p.Name == "Foo")
        .First();

var client = new Client() { Id = 1, Name = "Fred" };

var order = new Order()
{
    Id = 1,
    ClientId = client.Id,
    StartDate = DateTime.Now
};

var orderProduct = new OrderProduct()
{
    Id = product.Id,
    OrderId = order.Id,
    Name = product.Name,
    Quantity = 1
};

product.Quantity -= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand it correctly that you have a list of products you can order and one order is always done by one single client?

Then I would create a table for the clients with their data and an id, then I would create a table with the different products and give each product an id. I would give each order the client id and the product id and what data  else you may have (start date, finnish date, etc.) (An own order id can be helpful too)

Like this you can find every order easily by the client or by the product. But make sure that the ids aren't changing.

Comment: Yes, one order is done by a single client and he can order one or more products. but there is no list, it's custom products. i tried both variants, but the problem is that the order id will increment and i will have three different orders for the same client and products, instead of one order id for a client with two or more products.

Comment: @Chriss_1982
Above in your question you state, that you have a product table where each product has an id, So my solution should still work.
I think one problem is that one order only can have one product in my solution for this I would give instead of the product Id an string with multiple Id's with a number of how many the client wants in front of it. You can divide those as you want, as long as you are still able to separate them later.